# Jenkins pass parameters to testNG Java

Tags: java, selenium, parameters, jenkins, testng

I am working on a test automation framework using testNG, Selenium and Jenkins. The code is working fine, it reads one or more csv files and uses that as test data. I run the test from Jenkins.

```
package test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class runTest {
private WebDriver myDriver = null;

    @BeforeTest
    public void openBrowser(){
        System.out.println("This test automation framework is created by --- for ---");
        //Set browser
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Temp//chromedriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C://Temp//IEDriverServer.exe");

        //Instantiate new WebDriver object with browser of choice
        myDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //myDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        //myDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        myDriver.get("http://localhost/tests/");
    }


    @Test (dataProvider="provideData")
    public void csvTest(String stepNr, String timeWaitMil, String waitForElement, String clickOnCssNameXpathLink, 
                        String valueInTextBox, String backspaceText, String assertReturnTrueFalse, 
                        String assertBy, String getUrl, 
                        String deleteCookie, String snapshot, String specialSnapshot){



        // Click on a something based on css, name xpath or link
        if (!"-".equals(clickOnCssNameXpathLink)){
            myDriver.findElement(By.name(clickOnCssNameXpathLink)).click();
        }

        // Enter value in textbox
        if (!"-".equals(valueInTextBox)){
            myDriver.findElement(By.name(clickOnCssNameXpathLink)).sendKeys(valueInTextBox);
        }


        // Delete cookies
        if (!"-".equals(deleteCookie)){
            myDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();           
        }

        // Make snapshot of whole page
        if (snapshot.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            // take the screenshot of full page
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)myDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            // prepare date to use in filename
            Date d = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
            // Save screenshot
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\Temp\\screenshots\\full_page_" +dateFormat.format(d)+ ".png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Could not make screenshot");
            }       
        }

    } 


    @DataProvider
    public Iterator<Object []> provideData() throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        //Array with multiple csv's
        String csvFiles[] = {"C:/Users/---/Desktop/JES2.0/testingSelenium/testNG/data.csv", "C:/Users/---/Desktop/JES2.0/testingSelenium/testNG/data2.csv"};

        List<Object []> testCases = new ArrayList<>();

        //loop through csv files
        for(String csvFile:csvFiles){
                String[] data= null;
                //read csv file
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

                //Skip first line in the csv file, because that only contains the column names
                String line = br.readLine();

                //loop through csv and split parameters by comma sign ,
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    // use comma as separator
                    data= line.split(",");
                    testCases.add(data);
                }//end of while loop

            }// end of for loop
        return testCases.iterator();        
    }


    @AfterTest
    public void closeBrowser(){
        //close browser
        myDriver.quit();
    }

}
```

As you can see, the browser, the url and the CSV files are hardcoded. I want to be able to pass these as parameters. What is the best way to do this? Is it possible to pass them through Jenkins?

I am thinking of building a dashboard where I can specify what tests (csv files) to run using which browser.

This is the Jenkins batch command I am running

```
java -cp C:\Users\---\Desktop\JES2.0\testingSelenium\testNG\libs\selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar;C:\Users\---\Desktop\JES2.0\testingSelenium\testNG\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins have a [built-in parameters handling](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), which is quite flexible in it's own way. But in this case, since you want to pass a filename as parameter, you can easily combine that functionality with a [Filesystem List Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Filesystem+List+Parameter+Plug-in), which can build the list based on a regexp that will parse list of files.

If you use Maven or Ant, you can embed that parameter within your build process, in a form similar to this:

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <environment>${env.PARAM}</environment>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
            <suiteXmlFiles> 
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

With this you can read the parameter that was passed on to Maven - in Jenkins using it's internal caller, and on command line with:

```
mvn install -Denv.PARAM=VALUE
```

So it should work either way...