# How to pass parameter from jenkins to selenium

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm using jenkins and selenium.

I need to send the testing url to selenium server from jenkins.

Under General Tab

Jenkins String parameter: `Name = APP, Default Value = http://localhost/basecode/`

Under Post-build Actions

Trigger parameterized build on other `projects -> Predefined parameters -> Parameters -> SEL_APP=$APP`

Above mentioned `SEL_APP` value needs to be written in the selenium bat file.

Suggestions are most welcome :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using maven then you can pass the parameters through maven command.

```
mvn clean test -Duser=value1 -Dpass=value2
```

If you are building the Jenkins job with parameters then you can use jenkins parameters in maven command as

```
clean test -Duser=$jenkinsparam1 -Dpass=$jenkinsparam1
```

jenkinsparam1 - Jenkins parameter while building a job.

In the code you can use them as

```
String s1 = System.getProperty("user");
String s2 = System.getProperty("pass");
```

Comment: i'm not using maven. so, any other suggession..?

Comment: might be this link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380231/jenkins-pass-parameters-to-testng-java

Comment: how to you trigger the build/automation execution from jenkins then?

Comment: I'm building from the "Build Now" option in the jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Use [File Operations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/File+Operations+Plugin) to create a bat file.

Add File Operations build step and with in it add File Create Operation. It creates the bat file with the contents provided in text area.

Comment: i'm not creating a bat file in run time. i created the file manually in the selenium

Answer (score 0):

Use `%parameter_name%` in your bat file, it would directly pick it from Jenkins.

Comment: i'm using %SEL_APP% in the bat file. but the value is not replacing. any other thing need to add or modify in jenkins..?