# How can I test different environments in cucumber framework using Jenkins parameters?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

Perhaps some one can help me. I am using cucumber BDD Page Object Model framework, I am testing dev and staging environments. In Jenkins in parameters we provided different URLs to both environments. DB verification have to be done only in dev. After I push the code, we have to be able to choose environment in Jenkins with no framework modification. How can I store that in framework? I was trying use if condition, but it doesn’t work for some reason.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565401/how-to-pass-parameter-from-jenkins-to-selenium.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I am looking for.